# Remove/uninstall ads from social networking sites on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, adware, advertisements

I have recently been noticing some ads that get displayed on my fb timeline or other social networking pages.These ads are not the usual ones that seem to be coming from the site but are attached to page anywhere.

What could be the possible cause.I have tried clearing cookies,yet they appear on social networking site pages.

Is it an adware if so how to go about removing them from google chrome browser.

Comment: Do you use [Ad block plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom) add-on for chrome?

Comment: Please [**edit**](http://superuser.com/posts/439409/edit) your question to include a list of all Google Chrome extensions you currently have installed.

Comment: @avirk Nope.Would installing that benefit?

Comment: @techie updated the comment and linked to it see if it helps.

Comment: @iglvzx I am not using any extensions as of present(acc to my knowledge).How can i check which are the present extensions in the browser

Comment: @techie Go to `chrome://chrome/extensions` using the address bar. It will list all your extensions.

Comment: Click on the **Wrench** button and select **Settings** and at the left tab you will see the **Extension** option.

Comment: @iglvzx ah! I forgot about the address bar.

Comment: "There was a problem adding the item to Chrome. Please refresh the page and try again."Its giving this error when trying to install Ad block plus

Comment: @all there are no extensions installed as of now.

Comment: @techie I have the same problem from time to time. Try restarting your computer and/or resetting your internet connection.

Comment: What is your chrome version?

Comment: @avirk I guess its 14.0.814.0

Comment: @techie don't guess just check it and update it right now if its old. Type in address bar and see the version `chrome://version/ `

Comment: @all Why cant i find Update Google Chrome option inside my wrench icon of my present version.

Comment: @all Kudos it worked.I installed latest version and the problem is solved!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Adblock Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb) to remove Ads from social networks and other websites.

Comment: "There was a problem adding the item to Chrome. Please refresh the page and try again."Its giving this error when trying to install.

Comment: try the other AdBlock extension available for chrome:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom

Comment: Tried this too.Again the same error.What could be the cause :(

Comment: What version of google chrome are you running?

Comment: I guess its 14.0.814.0

Comment: That's ancient. The latest stable version is 19.0.1084.56.

Comment: That's an old version of chrome and the extensions cant be installed because they're not compatible with old versions of chrome.
Try updating your chrome by following the instruction here:
http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95414  after that try to install the extension again

Comment: Will updating the version erase the bookmarks and other history?

Comment: No updating won't affect any bookmarks or history

Comment: @techie no it will not erase anything.

Comment: okay thanks shall try doing this,hopefully it should resolve the issue.

Comment: @all Why cant i find Update Google Chrome option inside my wrench icon of my present version.

Comment: @techie press the wrench icon > About google chrome > It will check for updates automatically.

Comment: @Nima Its showing "Update server not available Error-3"

Comment: It surely is not coz of a poor network connection, what else could be the reason

Comment: @techie based on google chrome troubleshooting:

Error 3 is a failure to communicate with Google Update.
Check if you're running Vista/ 7 and you have configured Google Chrome to always run as administrator.
This is a known issue with the Google Chrome auto-updating mechanism and can be avoided by simply running Google Chrome as a normal user. Additionally, keep in mind that for security reasons we recommend that you don't elevate the privilege of Google Chrome to administrator.

Comment: Its for Wdows XP."for security reasons we recommend that you don't elevate the privilege of Google Chrome to administrator"what exactly does this mean.

Comment: It means you shouldn't set the property of google chrome executable file to "Run as Administrator". 
Anyway, you can download the new version of google chrome directly and install it. It won't affect your profile. For safety, first export your bookmarks (http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96816) and then install the new version. If the bookmarks aren't imported automatically, you can import it by yourself using the import function in chrome options.

Comment: @Nima Thanks so much.I have saved the bookmarks.Now should i go ahead and install a new version of chrome.Before that should i uninstall the present version?

Comment: No that's usually not necessary.

Comment: Kudos it worked.I installed latest version and the problem is solved!!!

Answer (score 0):

Awhile back I downloaded a copy of Paint.Net but didn't pay close enough attention to where I grabbed it from and it installed a number of spyware programs that added ads directly into my Facebook timeline. I can't remember the name of the program but I was able to uninstall if from the Control Panel. I would check there for programs you don't recognize and get an anti-spyware program and scan your computer.

Comment: Yeah thats exactly the first thing i did.Check for any malicious programs,but nothing seemed wrong there.In fact my other browsers seem to be working fine except chrome,which proves that its infected some way.